# Background image scrolls vertically but sticks to the side of container

Tags: html, css, image, css-position

I have a standard container with a width of 1080px. I am wanting a floating image to appear on the right side of the container but when you scroll down, the image scrolls down also. I am also wanting the floating image to stick to the right side of the conainter even when you resize the window browser.

I have tried putting the parent div in position relative and the floating image with a position absolute and the image will stay to the right side of the parent div but when I scroll down it stays the same position instead of scrolling down.

This is the code that I have used so far -

CSS -

```
.santa-wrapper{
position: relative;
width: 1200px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.santa{
background-image: url("images/santa-head.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position: absolute;
top: 60%;
right: -20px;
width: 180px;
height: 200px;
z-index: 1;
}

.santa-body{
background-image: url("images/santa-body.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;   
position: absolute;
top: 60%;
right: -20px;
width: 180px;
height: 200px;
z-index: -1;
}
```

HTML -

```
<div class="santa-wrapper">
<div class="santa"></div>
<div class="santa-body"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the background image to stick to the bottom right you will need to add this code into your CSS.

```
background-position: right bottom;
```

To get the div to scroll down I think you will need to include some Javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.

I am wanitng th eimage to stick to the right side but not at the bottom, maybe about 100px from the top.

Answer (score 0):

You can use position:fixed;

```css
.fixed-right {
    position:fixed;
    right:0px;
    top:20px;
  }
```

```html
<img class="fixed-right" src="yourimage.jpg" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment.

Will this work for a background image? As the two images are background images.